# Applying the Service Cloud Feature Licence to Salesforce Platform Users?

Tags: case, case-object

According to the Salesforce Platform Licence Details page:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_communities_lightning_platform_details.htm&type=5

Lightning Platform licences require a Service Cloud Licence to access Cases:

[image: Lightning Platform Object Access Table]

[image]

However I am unable to assign the Service Cloud Licence to the Platform licence Users - the checkbox is greyed out (we have available Service Cloud licences in our org):

[image: Service Cloud User checkbox greyed out]

Documentation: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=console2_assign_service_feature_license.htm&type=5

As it stands currently, out Platform licence Users cannot access Cases at all, which is sub-optimal - even having read only access would be great when talking to a Customer about a booking if they can see any open or historical Cases this customer has they are better informed to proceed with making a booking etc.

It seems to me that the Platform Licence details page mis-represents the actual access of the Platform licence - which is hard to believe but I can't see any other way to read it!

Any advice and opinions gratefully received.

Matt

Comment: What kind of license you have with salesforce. For example if you have agreement for app cloud license you can not use cases.

Comment: Have you tried contacting SF support? Maybe there's a ask to be enabled feature that you need to look for.